# Canvas Collision Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, canvas, collision-detection

I have two arrays, one of them is to display the tiles on a map and the other is to detect collision. At the moment I can't move my player at all and the colArray doesn't seem to be working properly. 
Would anyone mind taking a look at my code?

My colArray is the following (I've also included a fiddle below):

```
function loadCollision() {
    var colArray = [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ];
    var posiX = 0;
    var posiY = 0;

    for (var x = 0; x < colArray.length; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < colArray[x].length; y++) {
            if (colArray[i][j] === 0) {                
            }
            if (colArray[i][j] == 1) {
                  $('#player').stop(); // stop player from moving
            }

            posX += 32;
        }
        posiX = 0;
        posiY += 32;
    }
}
```

and here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/c7tk1ks6/5/

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the console of your browser, you just made a typo, iterating on x,y , then using i,j. For me it is a non-reproducible bug so you might just as well delete this question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c7tk1ks6/7/ I fixed it but if I change any of the 0 values to a 1 in the colMap, the player disappears, any ideas?